# Converting STRING to INT in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a column of Strings that represent hours like this: 00:11:34. And I need to sum the column but I can't do it since they are strings, moreover I can't convert it directly to ints because of the ':' in between. What should I do to get the sum of this hours and get the result in minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a String Tokenizer and then Integer.parseInt

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("00:11:34",":");  
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {  
   System.out.println(st.nextToken());  
}
```